# Lipschitz continuity of a vector function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have a system of two differential equations:
\begin{align}
r'(t) = v(t)\\
v'(t) = \frac{-GM}{r^2(t)}
\end{align}
With the initial condition that $r(0) = r_0$ and $v(0) = 0$
coming directly from newtons law of gravitation $r''(t) = -\frac{GM}{r^2(t)}$ where $r \in [r_{min};\infty], t \in [0;\infty], v \in [-\infty,\infty]$

Rewriting this into vector form yields $y(t) = \langle r(t),v(t) \rangle$ and $f(y(t)) = \langle v(t),-\frac{GM}{r^2(t)} \rangle$. Thus the system of equations can be summarized as:
\begin{align}
y'(t) = f(y(t))\\
y(0) = \langle r_0,0 \rangle
\end{align}
Now I have to find out if $f(y(t))$ is lipschitz continous and I would like to know if I have done it correctly.

Lipschitz continuity for a vector function:
\begin{align}
||f(y_1)-f(y_2)|| \leq L||y_1-y_2|| \text{ holds for all } r_1,r_2 \in [r_{min};\infty], t_1,t_2 \in [0;\infty], v_1,v_2 \in [-\infty,\infty]\\
\end{align}
Rewriting:
\begin{align}
\sqrt{(v_1-v_2)^2+(-\frac{GM}{r_1^2}+\frac{GM}{r_2^2})^2} \leq L \sqrt{(v_1-v_2)^2+(r_1-r_2)^2}\\
(v_1-v_2)^2+\bigg(\frac{-Gm}{r_1^2}+\frac{Gm}{r_2^2}\bigg)^2 \leq L^2((v_1-v_2)^2+(r_1-r_2)^2)\\
\end{align}
Now I split this inequality up in two:
\begin{align}
|(v_1-v_2)| \leq L|(v_1-v_2)| \text{ and } |\frac{-Gm}{r_1^2}+\frac{Gm}{r_2^2}| \leq L|(r_1-r_2)|
\end{align}
The first is trivially solved by $L \geq 1$. Rewriting the second:
\begin{align}
Gm|(-\frac{1}{r_1^2|(r_1-r_2)|}+\frac{1}{r_2^2|(r_1-r_2)|})| \leq L
\end{align}
Now as $r_1-r_2$ can be made arbitrarily small this expression can be made arbitrarily large and is thus not lipschitz continous.

My intuition tells me that this should be lipschitz continous since (I think) there is only one unique solution. So am I right or I have I done anything wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't simplify the second expression good enough. Note that:
$$\frac{1}{r_1^2}-\frac{1}{r_2^2}= \frac{(r_2-r_1)(r_1+r_2) }{r_1^2r_2^2}$$